# Getting IP address for remote selenium node that the browser instance(test) runs on

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm a `selenium` and `C#` beginner.

I have a `selenium` hub set up along with 6 remote selenium nodes registering to this hub (using `C#` for my automation framework).

When I run my tests, I need to log the IP address for the remote node that each test runs on. Is this programatically possible using C#?

Comment: Hope [this](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/1766772) or [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/167ad2/get-ip-address-using-C-Sharp-code/) might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) into your project from NuGetpackage and then paste the code snippet:

```
private static void GetNodeIp(string hostName , string port , string sessionId)
{
    try
    {               
        RestClient client = new RestClient("http://" + hostName + ":" + port + "/grid/api/testsession?session=" + sessionId);
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        var resp = client.Execute(req);
        dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp.Content);
        Console.WriteLine("Test Will run on Machine : {0}" ,new Uri(jsonData.proxyId.ToString()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

And then call the above method like this:

```
GetNodeIp("localhost", "4444", "ffgfdg-fgfgf-fgdfgfg-sdsdfdsf");
```

You should be able to get the session id using the code snippet below:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(hubUrl), _capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
 string session = driver.SessionId.ToString();
```

Don't forget to initialize [Desired capabilities](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_DesiredCapabilities.htm) object.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to now their IP addresses?  After the nodes register with the hub, they are already connected.  When you run the test using RemoteWebDriver, the RemoteWebDriver automatically connects with the hub and transmit the tests to the nodes that are already registered.  To make sure the nodes are already registered, invoke the hub via your browser http://localhost:4444 if it resides locally in your system.  You should see a configuration tab for each node, or just one with several browsers if you invoked more than one browser in one node. The nodes need the IP address of the hub, but not the other way around if this makes sense.